# How i can control when field of type reference is null in Firebase Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working with fields of type `reference` in Firestore.

This is my code:

```
    DocumentReference calRef = db.collection(calendarPath).document(fechaYYYY).collection(fechaMM).document(fechaDD);
    calRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot calSnapshot,
                            @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            DocumentReference dataRef=calSnapshot.getDocumentReference("1");
            if (e != null || dataRef==null) {
                launchVolley();
                return;
            }

            if (calSnapshot != null && calSnapshot.exists()) {
                dataRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        mBreviario = dataSnapshot.toObject(Breviario.class);
                        Log.d(TAG,dataSnapshot.toString());
                        showData();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                launchVolley();
            }
        }
    });
```

Here `DocumentReference dataRef=calSnapshot.getDocumentReference("1");` I take one reference to another document.

Here `if (calSnapshot != null && calSnapshot.exists()) {` I try to get the data at this reference.

This works fine, but if the document reference taked on `dataRef` not exists really  i'm having NPE Error.

My Log shows that:

> ```
> D/OficioActivity: DocumentSnapshot{key=liturgia/lh/1/307040501,
> metadata=SnapshotMetadata{hasPendingWrites=false, isFromCache=false},
> doc=null}
> ```

Here I can see: `doc=null` i think it's my document reference. But, who I can control when that is null.

Here I tryed to do this control:

```
        if (e != null || dataRef==null) {
            launchVolley();
            return;
        }
```

But is not working.

Comment: Since you're not showing the actual contents of the document, I can only assume that the document exists, but the field `1` in that document is null.  What are you expecting it to be instead?

Comment: Also, you should check to see if the document exists *first* before trying to access any of its fields.  You're doing the reverse - accessing a field first before checking for existence.

Comment: @DougStevenson the field `1` exists, is a field of type reference, the result of field `1` is that: `key=liturgia/lh/1/307040501`(see Log of snapshot). The problem is when `liturgia/lh/1/307040501` not exists... who I can control that?

Comment: There's no obligation that any document reference must point to an existing document.  If you want to know if it exists, you have to query it.

Comment: @DougStevenson here i'm queryng it: `dataRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {` but i don't know how I can control if it's null